# Oracle ApeX (PL/SQL)- Creating Bind variable out of JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Working with Oracle APEX 4.2.x. I have created a popup that will be able to search for Bank Accounts (Rekening in my language). It will return an ID which we will use in a Dynamic Action to get all the information about that Bank Account.

We have to use it twice on the same page, on multiple pages, so our solution was to create a hidden field with the name of the input-field containing the (to-be filled) Rekening_ID. This will be passed on to our PopUp function which will forward this to the passback function. This way we can use this popup for multiple textfields.

This is the function in the HTML Header of the to-be filled page.

**NOTE: the paramItem is something like: P2_BANK_ACCOUNT_ID**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function callMyPopup (paramItem) {
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById(paramItem).value;
    var url;
  url = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:3:&APP_SESSION.::::P3_HIDDEN:' + hiddenField;
  w = open(url,"winLov","Scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=800,height=600");
  if (w.opener == null)
  w.opener = self;
  w.focus();
  }
</script>
```

This is the passBack function (which is called in the 'link' column of the Bank Account Report).

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
    function passBack(hidden_field, rekening_id)
    {
    opener.document.getElementById(hidden_field).value = rekening_id;
    close();
    }
</script>
```

So on the popup page, the value of P3_HIDDEN is set to the value of paramItem, which contains the textfield we will use to passBack.

This hidden_field needs to be passed on to the passback function. Now I stored the value in P3_HIDDEN but it's in a different region as the Report with the 'link' column. This way, when I use #HIDDEN# it will pass literally `passBack('#HIDDEN#',1)` for example. But I need this to be the value or P3_HIDDEN. Now I thought this would be possible by making it a Bind variable.

**Question: How can I get my P3_HIDDEN field content into a bind variable, or into the passBack function while the select link is in another region?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was: instead of`#P3_HIDDEN#`in passBack, call `$v('P3_HIDDEN')`